# Number of arguments of composition in haskell

Tags: haskell, composition

Recently I have been learning about compositions in haskell and am now a bit confused concerning this example.

```
(const . min) 3 0 4
```

As a result I get 3, so internally it must be computed like:

```
const (min 3) 0 4
```

But I thought since min takes two arguments, it should look like this:

```
const (min 3 0) 4
```

So apparently the composition only takes this one argument, in this case 3, instead of all the arguments for min like I expected it to. Does that mean compositions only take one argument per default or what am I not getting here?

Comment: All Haskell functions take one argument. E.g. `min 3 0` applies the (1-arg) function `min` to argument `3`. The result is a (1-arg) function, that is then applied to `0`. The result of that is the number `0`. We of course like to consider `min` as a 2-arg function, but technically there's no such a thing in Haskell. Coherently, composition composes two (1-arg) functions. To compose "2-arg" functions (i.e., 1-arg returning 1-arg functions) one would need some other operator, or simply use a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

You can answer your question by manually evaluating the initial expression.

```
(const . min) 3 0 4
⇒ (\x -> const (min x)) 3 0 4    * defn of (.)
⇒ (const (min 3)) 0 4            * function application
⇒ ((\x y -> x) (min 3)) 0 4      * defn of const
⇒ (\y -> min 3) 0 4              * function application
⇒ (min 3) 4                      * function application
⇒ 3                              * because 3 is less than 4
```

It is worth noting that function application is left-associative, so, `f x y` means the same as `(f x) y`.

It is also worth noting that `\x y -> z` means the same as `\x -> \y -> z`.